# Add fields from another model to the admin site

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-contrib

My `Profile` model has a `OneToOne` relation with Django's built-in `User` model.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

If I want to change user's password or properties like `Active` or `Superuser` I have to do it in one Change User page, and to edit `verified` property I have to go to another.

Is there any way to merge this:

[image]

And this:

[image]

Into one form so I can edit everything about a user in one page?

**Edit 1**:

As you guys suggested the `StackedInline` approach, let's see how it turns out.

Please first look at Django's default Admin site (first screenshot above):

1. Everything is grouped in sections and sections have titles.
2. Look at how the password information is displayed.
3. There's a link to change the password.

Now I implement the `StackedInline` solution.

Please note that this is in the `admin.py` of my `myapp`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Register your models here.


class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline, )


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Now let's look at Admin site:

[image]

1. Everything is scattered. Sections and their titles are gone (Personal info, Permissions, etc).
2. Password field shows the hashed password. All other information is gone.
3. There's no link to change the password.

**Edit 2**:

To solve the problem of **Edit 1** I look at the source code of Django (https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/admin.py) and add update my code as below:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline, )
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {"fields": ("username", "password")}),
        (("Personal info"), {"fields": ("first_name", "last_name", "email")}),
        (
            ("Permissions"),
            {
                "fields": (
                    "is_active",
                    "is_staff",
                    "is_superuser",
                    "groups",
                    "user_permissions",
                ),
            },
        ),
        (("Important dates"), {"fields": ("last_login", "date_joined")}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (
            None,
            {
                "classes": ("wide",),
                "fields": ("username", "password1", "password2"),
            },
        ),
    )

    filter_horizontal = (
        "groups",
        "user_permissions",
    )
    
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Now I have **two** sections in the Admin site:

The section on the top shows almost everything (except that the password field is still different and there's no link to change the password and also the `verified` field is **not** there) but sections and titles are back.

**Then there's this additional and completely unnecessary part:**

[image]
[image]

As you can see:

1. All fields of information about the user is repeated
2. Look at the password field
3. Information is not grouped in sections with titles
4. `verified` filed appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP can use one of the [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) objects such as [`StackedInline`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.StackedInline). This allows one to create inline forms providing one the ability to edit models on the same page as a parent model.

Adapting for OP's case, it would be something like

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ProfileInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Now OP's admin site is set up to edit Profile objects inline from the User detail page.

Comment: @OmidShojaee What I answered, based on the question and the initial requirements, was the way to solve the problem.
The new Edit is raising different requirements and by itself can be understood as follow up questions and that is not a good practice. [See here why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266768/5675325) (those are called [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332820/7109869)). You're welcome to ask a new question. Most likely you'll get the needed help here.

Comment: The initial requirement still stands: add one field to the "Create and Edit" pages of a user. I never asked for a solution that messes up those pages completely. After applying your solution the whole thing is unusable because I'm not able to update user's password anymore. Maybe I should've mentioned that I don't want to lose Admin site's functionality. I just thought that's obvious.

Comment: @OmidShojaee First of all the question has two images and asks how can the field be added. No effort shown from your side at all. You got the answer in how to add the field. And it worked since that's the standard way to solve it. However, now you also want to ensure a particular customization. That's the natural development process. One problem might lead to another.
You're welcome to use any combination of features you deem fit for that, such as `fields`, `list_display`, `fieldsets`, `ordering`, ... or even other strategies, or ask a different question if you don't know how.

Comment: Actually I tried ```fieldsets``` before and faced the same issue with password field So I appreciate if you look at that too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73816296/password-field-is-visible-and-not-encrypted-in-django-admin-site

Answer (score 0):

## User model Extension vs Inheritance.

Your profile model only add some elements to user. In this case Model inheritance can be better.

```
# models.py
class Profile(user):
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

after that you can achieve all fields for user and for profile:

```
# admin.py
class ProfileAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    fields = '__all__'
```

## if you don't want to switch on Model inheritance.

You can use  InlineModel in UserAdmin to change related model.

```
# admin.py
class ProfileInline(StackedInline):
    model=Profile

class UserAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline, )
```

Comment: I updated my question. By the way ```fileds = '__all__'``` doesn't work here.

Answer (score -1):

you can use override AbstractUser from model Django so you can merge user in one place like this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
   verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and you need to add this line to Django settings.py file so that Django knows to use the new User class:

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
```

then make sure to migrate :

```bash
(env)$ python manage.py makemigrations
(env)$ python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: So you mean if I override AbstractUser, ```verified``` field is going to somehow appear in the Admin site? No it doesn't.

Comment: @OmidShojaee , yes it will show , try it and get back to here so you can remove this comment or modify it.